# How to get blob list from Azure using WasbHook in Airflow DAG

Tags: python, azure, airflow, azure-blob-storage, keyword-argument

I have a simple DAG for working with Azure Blob Storage.

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.hooks.wasb_hook import WasbHook
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

azure = WasbHook(wasb_conn_id='connect_to_azure')

args = {
    "owner": "Airflow",
    "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2)}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="wasb_sensor_test",
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags=['poc', 'azure'])  
    
def get_blob_list():
    blob_list = azure.check_for_prefix(container_name='MY_CONTAINER_NAME', prefix='MY_PREFIX')
    
print_blob_list = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_blob_list',
    python_callable=get_blob_list,
    dag=dag)
    

print_blob_list
```

And I want to get a list with blobs regarding appropriate container and prefix. As I understand from code source of the hook (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6d612efc7e19fff01b0da98bc345320edde70237/airflow/providers/microsoft/azure/hooks/wasb.py#L73) it's possible to do if call the **check_for_prefix** function and to add and additional argument in place of **kwargs.
Something like

```
blob_list = azure.check_for_prefix(container_name='MY_CONTAINER_NAME', prefix='MY_PREFIX', blob_list_return)
```

But I don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Did you get some error?

Comment: @JoyWang, when I change function calling like `blob_list = azure.check_for_prefix(container_name='MY_CONTAINER_NAME', prefix='MY_PREFIX', blob_list_return)` I get a message _Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/test_sensor.py] positional argument follows keyword argument (test_sensor.py, line 26)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. All arguments from ***kwargs* in **check_for_prefix** function are passed in calling **BlockBlobService.list_blobs**(..., ***kwargs*) function inside.

Answer (score 1):

For WasbHook with updated Azure Blob Storage library v12 get_blobs_list still works as it was for BlockBlobService. Only the difference is that it returns a list of blob names.

```
azure.get_blobs_list(container_name,prefix)
```